# Array to csv prints the nested Array value

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I am having problems putting my array in to a CSV file.

My Array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [startedOn] => 2022-04-20T11:21:23.872
            [answeredOn] => 2022-04-20T11:21:35.865
            [finishedOn] => 2022-04-20T11:21:55.233
            [durationInSeconds] => 59

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [startedOn] => 2022-04-16T15:47:55.332
            [answeredOn] => 2022-04-16T15:48:25.698
            [finishedOn] => 2022-04-16T15:49:23.77
            [durationInSeconds] => 59
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [
```

I use this script to put the array in to a csv file:

```
$f = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

$firstLineKeys = false;
foreach ($resArr as $line)
{
    if (empty($firstLineKeys))
    {
        $firstLineKeys = array_keys($line);
        fputcsv($f, $firstLineKeys);
        $firstLineKeys = array_flip($firstLineKeys);
    }

    $line_array = array($line);
    foreach ($line as $value)
    {
        array_push($line_array,$value);
    }

    fputcsv($f, $line_array);
}
```

This works for the main part except that the first value of every line is "Array". 
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that you're initializing `$line_array` with `$line` as the first element, making it a 2-dimensional array.

But there's no need for `$line_array` at all, just use `fputcsv($f, $line);`